# Why doesn't the javascript return and display text?

Tags: google-apps-script

In the html and code.gs I have a page asking to select a date and then try to display a calendar title for an event on that date to the screen.

Here is the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" >
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the page</h1>
      <p>Please select a date below.</p>
      <p>Click Here: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /><p> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id='test'></div>

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
var dateSelected = $(this).val()
var displayText = google.script.run.listEvents(dateSelected);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=displayText;
$("#test").text(displayText);
});

</script>
```

Here is the code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function listEvents(dateSelected) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CalendarId').getEventsForDay(new Date(dateSelected));
  if (calendar[0] == null) {
    var text = 'Nothing to show';
    return text;
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Number of events: ' + calendar[0].getTitle());
  }

}
```

In the if (calendar ==null) section I put Logger.log('nothing today') that logs just fine. So I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I'm returning or the type thats being returned because on the html page what displays is the text 'undefined'.

If I set the Jquery to $("#test").text($(this).val()); then it displays the date that was selected. Its only when I replace $(this).val() for displayText doesn't work.

I just replaced this line of code:
var displayText = google.script.run.listEvents(dateSelected);
with this:
var displayText = 'random text';
and sure enough the string 'random text' was shown on the screen. It must be the type of data that the gas script returns. Am I even able to return a string from a script or is it some restriction? Am I just missing some syntax?

Comment: Are you including the jquery library in your HTML? If not, `$` is undefined.

Comment: Oh yes the jquery library is in there, I just thought I'd save everyone for too long of code. If I set the Jquery to $("#test").text($(this).val()); then it displays the date that was selected. Its only when I replace $(this).val() for displayText does it not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just found the answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258674/server-side-code-not-working-in-google-app-script). You want to use **.withSuccessHandler** to get the return value, something like this:

```
<script>
function onSuccess(displayText) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=displayText;
  $("#test").text(displayText);
}
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
var dateSelected = $(this).val()
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).listEvents(dateSelected);
});

</script>
```

The code above is not tested, but was written quickly based on working examples.